# JAVA GC - Top classes collected after minor GC

Tags: optimization, garbage-collection, jvm

We have been monitoring an application of our laboratory these days. We found that minor GCs occur frequently and the total GC time is about 15 secs in 20 minutes.

Compared with the similar product of another company, we measured that the total GC time is about 8 secs.

We want to know which part of our code leads to the frequent allocation and reclaim of objects, so that we can optimize our code and try to catch up with others as much as we can.

We've tried to use jvisualvm to create heap dump and see the difference between two heap dump. However, the timing of creating heap dump is hard to handle and the creation is also very slow.

Is there any tool or method to know which classes are collected most during each minor GC?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you seeing any explicit gc calls in your gc stats???

Comment: @harshavmb What does explicit gc calls mean?  When we monitor with jvisualvm, we just find minor GC occurs frequently, the total minor GC time is about 14s in 20 minutes, and we need to make some changes to the code.

Comment: explicit gc calls are the calls made by your application to jvm to invoke gc. It can be called using the methods **System.gc();** or **Runtime.getRuntime().gc();**. Minor gc calls are to clear young generation objects located in Eden space. This shouldn't be a problem, major gc pauses the execution of other running threads, which is the real problem. I just want to check whether gc calls are implicit (jvm internal calls) or explicit (application calls to jvm to invoke jvm).

Comment: 15sec GC pause out of 20 minutes (wall time? CPU time?) is not really that much. it's a mere 1.25%. even cutting your GC time in half would only make it 0.5% faster.

Answer (score 0):

java profilers such as jmc, jprofiler or yourkit provide allocation recording or class histogram diffing which should tell you which classes are frequently allocated. Some can even tell you the allocation sites.

Alternatively you could try tweaking the GC to collect the young generation less often (by making it larger or relaxing pause time goals) which might increase efficiency.

> total GC time occupies a relatively large proportion of the running time

This is odd. It would normally trigger a GC overhead limit exceeded OOME, at least for the parallel collector, which is the default.

Comment: Thank you very much. Maybe I haven't stated clearly enough. Would you please read my update? We want to improve our application before tuning gc.